# Creating a table in SQL Server using SELECT ... INTO

Tags: sql-server, select-into

i am creating a table in sqlserver database using query like "SELECT Table1.* INTO Table2 FROM Table1"
here Table2 created successfully but it is not showing my database

when i again fire this query than it gives error that Table2 is already created but i can't see this in my database

i am refreshing my database also

so please help me if anyone has solution..

Comment: This is more a database question than a C# question. Please edit your title and tags, and state the database. Anyway, can you do `SELECT * FROM Table2` ? I thought so. So, the table is probably there.

Comment: are you looking in the right database? don't laugh, I've done it before!

Comment: Yes i can do this but still i can't see the table

Comment: @editors - any real reason to assume this is SQL Server?

Answer (score 2):

@Ramesh has the right idea.  In some situations (I think if your user is in the `db_owner` role?), `SELECT INTO` tables are created in the schema (the SQL 2005+ terminology) associated with your login.  This may be something like `YOURDOMAIN\username.Table2`.  If you go to select again from the same login, it will work fine, but chances are that other users will not be searching in your schema.

When in doubt, explicitly create the table in the `dbo` schema:

```
SELECT Table1.*
INTO dbo.Table2
FROM Table1
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried with the username.Table1, like

```
  dbo.table
```

Its very important to append the username for any db object, it enforces the user to select the objects which he got permission to view

Comment: but i can retrive data from this Table2 it means it is created but i can't see this table i had done it in asp.net web application & i can see this table but i can't see in windows application
i can't see any inserted data in table which i have already created manually

Comment: since you can't see that table - is it a temporary table (#tablename) by any chance?? Those are visible to the current connection only, by default.

Comment: do you know how can i see this table than help me

Comment: @harsh, pls expln wat it means "i cant see the table"? is it you cant see the table in sql query editor(ssms) or you fired a query from application and didnt get any result.. can you pls fire the query in sql editor and see whether will it return any rows?